# how to left align an itemize element

Tags: itemize

I would that the item are all left aligned.
Is it possible? and how?

```
\begin{frame}{PNEI}
    \begin{itemize}
        \begin{center}
          \item \textcolor{red}{P}sico
          \item \textcolor{red}{N}euro
          \item \textcolor{red}{E}ndocrino
          \item \textcolor{red}{I}mmunologia
        \end{center}
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

TIA

Renato

Comment: Removing `center`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the `center` environment which centres the content within the text block or, if you want the `itemize` centered but left-aligned, place it inside a fixed-width box (using `minipage` or [`varwidth`](//ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{PNEI}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item \textcolor{red}{P}sico
    \item \textcolor{red}{N}euro
    \item \textcolor{red}{E}ndocrino
    \item \textcolor{red}{I}mmunologia
  \end{itemize}

  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.265\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textcolor{red}{P}sico
      \item \textcolor{red}{N}euro
      \item \textcolor{red}{E}ndocrino
      \item \textcolor{red}{I}mmunologia
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Feel free to highlight what could be changed in order to address the downvote.

Comment: I really have nothing to do with the downvote, just came across this by chance. However, I can sort of see how somebody may downvote this. There is a comment by egreg and an answer by Hafid Boukhoulda, both of which are earlier and, sorry to be so frank, have substantial overlap with your answer. I guess it would not hurt to acknowledge these in your post. I like that Hafid Boukhoulda does that, which is why I upvoted their answer, even though I usually do not upvote answers that do not have a compilable code.

Comment: +1 in order to get a zero :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @egreg comment:

```
\begin{frame}{PNEI}
    \begin{itemize}
        %\begin{center}
          \item \textcolor{red}{P}sico
          \item \textcolor{red}{N}euro
          \item \textcolor{red}{E}ndocrino
          \item \textcolor{red}{I}mmunologia
        %\end{center}
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```